# Invalid number of parameters for "undefine". Got 0 expected 1!

Tags: solidity, truffle

I start my trial token sale contract, but it keep pop out this error when i test it with truffle.

[image]

Here my token sale contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

import "./DappToken.sol";

contract DappTokenSale {

    address admin;
    DappToken public tokenContract;

    constructor (DappToken _tokenContract) public {
        admin = msg.sender;
        tokenContract = _tokenContract;

    }   
}
```

Here my test js file:

```
var DappTokenSale = artifacts.require('./DappTokenSale.sol');

contract('DappTokenSale', function(accounts) {
    var tokenSaleInstance;

    it('initializes the contract with the correct values', function() {
        return DappTokenSale.deployed().then(function(instance) {
            tokenSaleInstance = instance;
            return tokenSaleInstance.address
        }).then(function(address) {
            assert.notEqual(address, 0x0, "has contract address");
            return tokenSaleInstance.tokenContract();
        })..then(function(address) {
            assert.notEqual(address, 0x0, "has token contract address");
        });
    });
});
```

and here my contract file:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract DappToken {
    string public name = "Dapp Token";
    string public symbol = "DToken";
    string public standard = "DToken v1.0";
    uint256 public totalSupply;

    event Transfer(
        address indexed _from,
        address indexed _to,
        uint256 _value
        );

    event Approval(
        address indexed _owner,
        address indexed _spender,
        uint256 _value
        );

    mapping(address => uint256) public balanceOf;
    mapping(address => mapping(address => uint256)) public allowance;

    constructor(uint256 _initialSupply) public {
        balanceOf[msg.sender] = _initialSupply;
        totalSupply = _initialSupply;
    }   

    function transfer (address _to, uint256 _value) public returns(bool success) {
        require(balanceOf[msg.sender] >= _value);
        balanceOf[msg.sender] -= _value;
        balanceOf[_to] += _value;

        emit Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
        return true;
    }

    function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) public returns(bool success) {
        allowance[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
        emit Approval(msg.sender, _spender, _value);
        return true;
    }

    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public returns(bool success) {

        require (_value <= balanceOf[_from]);
        require (_value <= allowance[_from][msg.sender]);

        balanceOf[_from] -= _value;
        balanceOf[_to] += _value;

        allowance[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;

        emit Transfer( _from, _to, _value);
        return true;
    }

}
```

I use web3js 1.0.x, what should i do ?

Comment: What is in `deployment.js` file at line 364?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written, the error occurs in the migration file. You are trying to deploy the token contract without specifying the initial supply.

You can read the [Truffle documentation](https://truffleframework.com/docs/truffle/getting-started/running-migrations#deployer-deploy-contract-args-options-) on how to pass arguments when deploying a contract.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what it should like in the `2_deploy_contracts.js` migration file:

```js
const DappToken = artifacts.require("./DappToken.sol");
const DappTokenSale = artifacts.require("./DappTokenSale.sol");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  const tokenPrice= 1000000000000000; //  .001 Ether
  deployer.deploy(DappToken,1000000);
  deployer.deploy(DappTokenSale,DappToken.address,tokenPrice);
};
```